# Difference between object and class in Scala

Tags: scala, class, object

I'm just going over some Scala tutorials on the Internet and have noticed in some examples an object is declared at the start of the example.

What is the difference between `class` and `object` in Scala?

Answer (score 696, accepted):

### tl;dr

- `class C` defines a class, just as in Java or C++.
- `object O` creates a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) object `O` as instance of some anonymous class; it can be used to hold static members that are not associated with instances of some class.
- `object O extends T` makes the object `O` an instance of `trait T`; you can then pass `O` anywhere, a `T` is expected.
- if there is a `class C`, then `object C` is the [companion object](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/singleton-objects.html#companion-objects) of class `C`; note that the companion object is **not** automatically an instance of `C`.

Also see Scala documentation for [object](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/singleton-objects.html) and [class](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/classes.html).

#### `object` as host of static members

Most often, you need an `object` to hold methods and values/variables that shall be available without having to first instantiate an instance of some class.
This use is closely related to `static` members in Java.

```
object A {
  def twice(i: Int): Int = 2*i
}
```

You can then call above method using `A.twice(2)`.

If `twice` were a member of some class `A`, then you would need to make an instance first:

```
class A() {
  def twice(i: Int): Int = 2 * i
}

val a = new A()
a.twice(2)
```

You can see how redundant this is, as `twice` does not require any instance-specific data.

#### `object` as a special named instance

You can also use the `object` itself as some special instance of a class or trait.
When you do this, your object needs to extend some `trait` in order to become an instance of a subclass of it.

Consider the following code:

```
object A extends B with C {
  ...
}
```

This declaration first declares an anonymous (inaccessible) class that extends both `B` and `C`, and instantiates a single instance of this class named `A`.

This means `A` can be passed to functions expecting objects of type `B` or `C`, or `B with C`.

#### Additional Features of `object`

There also exist some special features of objects in Scala.
I recommend to read the [official documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/singleton-objects.html).

- `def apply(...)` enables the usual method name-less syntax of `A(...)`
- `def unapply(...)` allows to create custom pattern matching [extractors](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/extractor-objects.html)
- if accompanying a class of the same name, the object assumes a special role when resolving [implicit parameters](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-parameters.html)

Comment: It will also define class A, and create all of the methods in object A as static methods on class A (for interfacing with Java). (Modulo a bug in Scala 2.7 that's been fixed in Scala 2.8)

Comment: @KenBloom really? I tried and doesn't work: scala> Commerce
res8: Commerce.type = Commerce$@6eb2756

scala> classOf[Commerce]
<console>:23: error: not found: type Commerce
              classOf[Commerce]
                      ^

scala> new Commerce
<console>:23: error: not found: type Commerce
              new Commerce
                  ^

Comment: @Hendy: Scala won't recognize the `Commerce` class, but the JVM and the Java language will. (That's how you can do `object Foo{ def main(args:Seq[String]) }` and expect the program to run.)

Comment: I think ziggystar's answer is more precise, the class is an anonymous class, unless a corresponding class named Commerce is explicitly defined (then Commerce object will be a companion object to the Commerce class)

Comment: Another simple explanation which is not entirely true. At least in Scala 2.9.1 I remember struggling passing the object as an instance of an interface in some cases.

Comment: @DavidApltauer I bet there are enough subtleties that are not covered by my answer. But those probably don't matter for most people reading this. And I had never problems with passing an object as an instance of some trait, which does not mean they don't exist; but it should work.

Answer (score 259):

A `class` is a definition, a description. It defines a type in terms of methods and composition of other types.

An `object` is a singleton -- an instance of a class which is guaranteed to be unique. For every `object` in the code, an anonymous class is created, which inherits from whatever classes you declared `object` to implement. This class cannot be seen from Scala source code -- though you can get at it through reflection.

There is a relationship between `object` and `class`. An object is said to be the companion-object of a class if they share the same name. When this happens, each has access to methods of `private` visibility in the other. These methods are not automatically imported, though. You either have to import them explicitly, or prefix them with the class/object name.

For example:

```
class X {
  // class X can see private members of object X
  // Prefix to call
  def m(x: Int) = X.f(x)

  // Import and use
  import X._
  def n(x: Int) = f(x)

  private def o = 2
}

object X {
  private def f(x: Int) = x * x

  // object X can see private members of class X
  def g(x: X) = {
    import x._
    x.o * o // fully specified and imported
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but could you perhaps point to an example about how to import methods into the companion object or how to prefix them?

Comment: @ithkuil Done. Sorry about the silly example, I couldn't think of a good and short one.

Comment: What if I want to use class method's in Object? Would that be possible? If I have a method of a class and I want to use it in Object, then if you try to import the class, you won't be able to. Eventually you have to make a constructor and call the method then. So, by making a companion object, you can access the methods of Object using import but not vice versa. Can someone please validate?

Comment: @piyushGoyal Not true. Say the object has a method `def f(x: X) = ???`, then it would be able to call private methods on `x`, of the companion class `X`.

Comment: Here X passed in the function is instance of class X I guess? If yes, then eventually you are using the object x to call the method of X class in the def f.. Right?

Comment: @piyushGoyal I've extended the example in the answer to exemplify what I meant.

Comment: @piyushGoyal Note that importing members has absolutely nothing to do with companions. You can import the members of any value in Scala.

Comment: First of all I would like to say thanks to you for taking so much effort in explaining things. :) I saw the example. So another question, I understand the logic you used in def g to use the 'o' val/def of class. My question is if I don't want to pass the object of A, I can't use the o directly by doing an import A._ directly in the Object. At the end you are eventually constructing an object of A as x and then using it. To explain it further the code object A { import A._ val random = o*o } will never work because the object A would never be able to identify import A._

Comment: @piyushGoyal Correct. 'object X' is a value, 'new X' is a value, but 'class X' is not.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral why do you say that an anonymous class is created? I've decompiled, looked at the code and it's a plain class. yes, there are two classes and one of them has `$` in its name (denotes usually a compiler generated class), but this is no indication of an anonymous class; as a matter of fact AFAIK you can't tell if that is a compiler generated class or an anonymous class by looking at the byte-code alone.

Comment: @Eugene Did you decompile Scala 2.7.x code? This is a really old answer.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral does it really matter? I mean I was trying to address the fact that in your answer you say that a class name that has `$` under it's name is an anonymous class (at least this is what I understood), but that is not mandatory, it could be a simple class, not _necessarily_ anonymous. does that make sense?

Comment: @Eugene Of course it does. How these things are implemented have changed with each Scala major version (Scala versions are epic.major.minor). Perhaps I was wrong, but it's possible that on Scala 2.7.x it _was_ an anonymous class.

Answer (score 82):

An object has exactly **one** instance (you can not call `new MyObject`). You can have **multiple** instances of a class.

Object serves the **same** (and some additional) **purposes** as the static methods and fields in Java.

Answer (score 23):

As has been explained by many, `object` defines a singleton instance. The one thing in the answers here that I believe is left out is that `object` serves several purposes.

- It can be the companion object to a `class`/`trait`, containing what might be considered static methods or convenience methods.
- It can act much like a module, containing related/subsidiary types and definitions, etc.
- It can implement an interface by extending a `class` or one or more `trait`s.
- It can represent a case of a `sealed trait` that contains no data. In this respect, it's often considered more correct than a `case class` with no parameters. The special case of a `sealed trait` with only `case object` implementors is more or less the Scala version of an enum.
- It can act as evidence for `implicit`-driven logic.
- It introduces a singleton type.

It's a very powerful and general construct. What can be very confusing to Scala beginners is that the same construct can have vastly different uses. And an `object` can serve many of these different uses all at once, which can be even more confusing.

Answer (score 22):

Defining an object in Scala is like defining a class in Java that has only static methods. However, in Scala an object can extend another superclass, implement interfaces, and be passed around as though it were an instance of a class. (So it's like the static methods on a class but better).

Answer (score 20):

The formal difference -

1. you can not provide constructor parameters for **Objects**
2. **Object** is not a type - you may not create an instance with new operator. But it can have fields, methods, extend a superclass and mix in traits.

The difference in usage:

- Scala doesn't have static methods or fields. Instead you should use `object`. You can use it with or without related class. In 1st case it's called a companion object. You have to:

  1. use the same name for both class and object
  2. put them in the same source file.
- To create a program you should use main method in `object`, not in `class`.

  ```
  object Hello {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      println("Hello, World!")
    }
  }
  ```
- You also may use it as you use singleton object in java.

Comment: "you can not provide constructor parameters for Objects"  Objects have the apply(...) method, which functions a lot like a constructor.  This leaves me a little confused.

Answer (score 8):

In scala, there is no `static` concept. So scala creates a singleton object to provide entry point for your program execution.
If you don't create singleton object, your code will compile successfully but will not produce any output. Methods declared inside Singleton Object are accessible globally. A singleton object can extend classes and traits.

**Scala Singleton Object Example**

```
object Singleton{  
    def main(args:Array[String]){  
        SingletonObject.hello()         // No need to create object.  
    }  
}  


object SingletonObject{  
    def hello(){  
        println("Hello, This is Singleton Object")  
    }  
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello, This is Singleton Object
```

In scala, when you have a class with same name as singleton object, it is called companion class and the singleton object is called companion object.

The companion class and its companion object both must be defined in the same source file.

**Scala Companion Object Example**

```
class ComapanionClass{  
    def hello(){  
        println("Hello, this is Companion Class.")  
    }  
}  
object CompanoinObject{  
    def main(args:Array[String]){  
        new ComapanionClass().hello()  
        println("And this is Companion Object.")  
    }  
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello, this is Companion Class.
And this is Companion Object.
```

In scala, a class can contain:

**1. Data member**

**2. Member method**

**3. Constructor Block**

**4. Nested class**

**5. Super class information etc.**

You must initialize all instance variables in the class. There is no default scope. If you don't specify access scope, it is public. There must be an object in which main method is defined. It provides starting point for your program. Here, we have created an example of class.

**Scala Sample Example of Class**

```
class Student{  
    var id:Int = 0;                         // All fields must be initialized  
    var name:String = null;  
}  
object MainObject{  
    def main(args:Array[String]){  
        var s = new Student()               // Creating an object  
        println(s.id+" "+s.name);  
    }  
}
```

I am sorry, I am too late but I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 7):

The *object* keyword creates a new singleton type, which is like a *class* that only has a single named instance. If you’re familiar with Java, declaring an *object* in Scala is a lot like creating a new instance of an anonymous class.

Scala has no equivalent to Java’s *static* keyword, and an *object* is often used in Scala where you might use a class with static members in Java.

Answer (score 6):

**Object** is a class but it already has(is) an instance, so you can not call `new ObjectName`. On the other hand, **Class** is just type and it can be an instance by calling `new ClassName()`.

Answer (score 3):

A class is just like any other class in other languages. You define class just like any other language with some syntax difference.

```
class Person(val name: String)
val me = new Person("My name")
```

However, object is a class with single object only. This makes it interesting as it can be used to create static members of a class using **companion object**. This companion object has access to private members of the class definition and it has the same name as the class you're defining.

```
class Person(var name: String) {

  import Person._

  def hi(): String = sayHello(name)
}

object Person {
  private def sayHello(name: String): String = "Hello " + name
}

val me = new Person("My name")
me.hi()
```

Also, noteworthy point is that object class is lazily created which is another important point. So, these are not instantiated unless they are needed in our code.

If you're defining connection creation for JDBC, you can create them inside object to avoid duplication just like we do in Java with singleton objects.

Answer (score 2):

The object is similar to the static class in Java to some extend, the static characteristic means the static class need not to create an object when putting to the JVM, it can be used by it's class name directly and the same instance(same data state) is shared wherever it is used.

Answer (score 2):

Scala class same as Java Class but scala not gives you any entry method in class, like main method in java. The main method associated with object keyword. You can think of the object keyword as creating a singleton object of a class that is defined implicitly.

more information check this article 
[class and object keyword in scala programming](https://blog.knoldus.com/2017/06/18/class-and-object-keyword-in-scala-programming/)

Answer (score -1):

If you are coming from java background the concept of class in scala is kind of similar to Java, but class in scala cant contain static members.

Objects in scala are singleton type you call methods inside it using object name, in scala object is a keyword and in java object is a instance of class