# Scala - are classes sufficient?

Tags: scala, class

Coming from Java I am confused by the class/object distinction of scala.
Note that I do not ask for the formal difference; there are enough
references on the web which explain this, and there are related questions on 
[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755345/scala-difference-between-object-and-class).

My questions are:

1. Why did the designers of scala
   choosed to make things more
   complicated (compared to Java or
   C#)? What disadvantages do I have to
   expect if I ignore this distinction
   and declare only classes?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you consider the approach Scala took to be more "complicated"? After working with each languages Scala's solution is by far the easiest, especially when inheritance and sub-typing come into play.

Answer (score 24):

Java classes contain two completely different types of members -- instance members (such as `BigDecimal.plus`) and static members (such as `BigDecimal.valueOf`). In Scala, there are **only** instance members. This is actually a simplification! But it leaves a problem: where do we put methods like `valueOf`? That's where objects are useful.

```
class BigDecimal(value: String) {
   def plus(that: BigDecimal): BigDecimal = // ...
}

object BigDecimal {
   def valueOf(i: Int): BigDecimal = // ...
}
```

You can view this as the declaration of anonymous class and a single instantiation thereof:

```
class BigDecimal$object {
   def valueOf(i: Int): BigDecimal = // ...
}
lazy val BigDecimal = new BigDecimal$object
```

When reading Scala code, it is crucial to distinguish types from values. I've configured IntelliJ to hightlight types blue.

```
val ls = List.empty[Int]  // List is a value, a reference the the object List
ls: List[Int]             // List is a type, a reference to class List
```

Java also has another degree of complexity that was removed in Scala -- the distinction between fields and methods. Fields aren't allowed on interfaces, except if they are static and final; methods can be overriden, fields instead are hidden if redefined in a subclass. Scala does away with this complexity, and only exposes methods to the programmer.

Finally, a glib answer to your second question: If you don't declare any objects, you're program may never run, as you to define the equivalent of `public static void main(String... args) {}` in Scala, you need at least one object!

Comment: The object keyword gives you a singleton class (under-the-hood anyway) and is Scala's replacement for static members.

Comment: Be aware that if you have a class named `Something` and an object named `Something` (in the same package), then those two are linked - the object is the *companion object* of the class, and the two can see each other's private members. Comparing it with Java: think of the methods in the class as the instance methods, and the methods in the object as the static methods that belong to that class.

Comment: Good point, Jesper. In addition, the companion object `T` of a class or trait `T` is in the implicit scope when searching for implicit values a type `X`, given that `T` or a subtype of `T` is a part of type `X`. This is used to find implicit views and implicit arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Scala doesn't have any notion of static methods with standard classes, so in those scenarios you'll have to use objects.  Interesting article here which provides a good intro:

http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/scala-for-java-refugees-part-3

(scroll down to Scala’s Sort-of Statics)

Answer (score 0):

One way to look at it is this. An executing program consists of a community of objects and threads. Threads execute code within the context of objects -- i.e. there is always a "this" object that a thread is executing within. This is a simplification from Java in the sense that in Java, there is not always a "this".  But now there is a chicken/egg problem. If objects are created by threads and threads are executed within objects, what object is the first thread initially executing within. There has to be a nonempty set of objects that exist at the start of program execution. These are the objects declared with the `object` keyword.