# In scala, is there any way to check if an instance is a singleton object or not?

Tags: scala

If I have an instance of an object, is there a way to check if I have a singleton object rather than an instance of a class?
Is there any method can do this? May be some reflection API?
I know that one difference is that the class name of a singleton object ends with a `$`, but this is not a strict way.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yep, using the little-documented `scala.Singleton` type:

```
def isSingleton[A](a: A)(implicit ev: A <:< Singleton = null) = 
  Option(ev).isDefined
```

And then:

```
scala> val X = new Foo(10)
X: Foo = Foo@3d5c818f

scala> object Y extends Foo(11)
defined object Y

scala> isSingleton(X)
res0: Boolean = false

scala> isSingleton(Y)
res1: Boolean = true
```

My `isSingleton` method is just a demonstration that provides a runtime boolean value that tells you whether or not an expression is statically typed as a singleton type, but you can also use `Singleton` as evidence at compile time that a type is a singleton type.

Comment: Why not use `ev ne null` instead of `Option(ev).isDefined`?

Comment: @Clashsoft No particular reason. The `null` default value is kind of a hack, and since it's not really the point I just wanted to keep things as principled otherwise as possible.

Comment: Also, are you sure `scala.Singleton` (still) exists? It's not in the `2.11` documentation, and it's not to be found in the GitHub repo either? Maybe you could add a link

Comment: @Clashsoft It's definitely [still there](https://github.com/scala/scala/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Singleton), but (as I note) not very documented.

Comment: It seems to be a [compiler builtin existential type](https://github.com/scala/scala/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=singletonclass&type=Code) (that also gets erased, so no `.isInstanceOf[Singleton]`).

Comment: Is there any documentation/mention about this at all?

Comment: @Jasper-M Well, it's mentioned a couple of times in the language specification, but no, not really.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I found the best solution to this problem:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
def isSingleton(value: Any) = currentMirror.reflect(value).symbol.isModuleClass
```

Base on [How to determine if `this` is an instance of a class or an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571881/how-to-determine-if-this-is-an-instance-of-a-class-or-an-object)