# How to check if a value is a Scala singleton object without a static type?

Tags: scala

The answer to [In scala, is there any way to check if an instance is a singleton object or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018355/in-scala-is-there-any-way-to-check-if-an-instance-is-a-singleton-object-or-not) explains how to check whether an instance is *statically known* to be an `object`. In other words, it won't work for this scenario:

```
object Obj
val x: Any = Obj
isSingleton(x)
```

Or even here:

```
trait Trait // not sealed
case Obj extends Trait
class Class extends Trait
val xs: Seq[Trait] = ...
xs.filter(isSingleton)
```

Unfortunately, I would like to handle this. Is there a good way to do this? Or at least a better one than `x.getClass.getName.endsWith("$")`?

Comment: Erasing type information using `Any` is a bad idea

Comment: Sure, but it's what you end up with once you start using reflection, and that's the context I need it in. At any rate, I've added a better example.

Comment: I have no idea how to do it, but I wonder what is the use case for this? Why do you case if an instance is a singleton in the first place? After all, it could be a singleton, without being an `object` ... `object Foo { val bar = new Trait {} }`. `bar` is a singleton too ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean "singleton" as in "Scala companion", then you can use something like this:

```
def isSingleton(x: Any): Boolean = {
  x.getClass.getFields.map(_.getName) contains "MODULE$"
}
```

Not that much better than checking `x.getClass.getName.endsWith("$")`, but still. For example:

```
case class Foo(x: Int)
object Foo

trait Trait // not sealed
object Obj extends Trait
class Class extends Trait

val xs = Seq(42, Obj, "okey", Foo(43), Foo, new Trait {}, (x: Int) ⇒ x * x)
println(xs map isSingleton)
// prints: List(false, true, false, false, true, false, false)
```