# How to read class/object in Scala documentation

Tags: scala

I just learned Scala.

When I read official documentation to look up `Array`, for example, it has two versions. One is for [Class](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Array), the other is for [Object](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Array$). I think I know the [difference between Class and Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755345/scala-difference-between-object-and-class) and when I need find methods of `Array`, I usually go to the Class version. I do not quite know when I need to go to this Object version.It seems when I want to create Multidimensional arrays, I need method(`ofDim`) in Object version instead of class version. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The identifier `Array` refers to either the *type* or its *companion object*, depending on context.

```
scala> Array('a', 'b', 'c')
res0: Array[Char] = Array(a, b, c)
```

`res0` is an instance of the `Array` type. `res0` is an object.

```
scala> Array
res1: Array.type = scala.Array$@1a69136
```

`res1` is the companion object. `res1` is an object. It is a singleton, meaning that there are no other objects of its type.

These two objects have different methods on them, because they're very different things.

Instances of the `Array` type have [the methods defined by the class](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Array). These are, naturally, the methods that operate on a particular `Array` instance. For example, the `length` method returns the length of the array. You need an instance to do this. It wouldn't make sense to write `Array.length` because that doesn't specify which array you want the length of. But `Array('a', 'b', 'c').length` is `3`.

The companion object has [the methods defined by the object](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Array$). These are the methods that do *not* require an `Array` instance. Companion objects will object contain methods that create instances, as is the case for `Array`. Hence `Array.ofDim(2, 2)` creates a 2x2 array. That method isn't defined by the class because instances shouldn't have it. For example, it wouldn't make much sense to write `Array('a', 'b', 'c').ofDim(2, 2)`, because the result (an empty 2x2 array) would have nothing to do with the instance that the method was called upon.

Comment: can I say that the methods defined by the object are similar to [static methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) in Java?

Comment: Yes, very much so. If you'd mentioned you were familiar with Java, I'd have just said that ;)

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, the class defines the actual implementation with methods to operate on the instances (in this case Array - methods like map, count, fold etc.).

The companion object on the other hand provides utility methods for creation (like apply...) (for Array in this case it mostly contains factory methods).

Answer (score 0):

The class methods operate on the class instance data. Like elements of an array for the Array class. The companion object methods usually operate on multiple instances of a class or create one.

The companion objects in Scala play the same role as static members in Java or C#. For example, for Array it mostly contain factory methods. I would not expect to see methods like `length` or `isEmpty` on the companion object and on the other hand I would expect to see factory methods on the instance of a class.