# How does the Singleton Object differ from a instance of class

Tags: scala

I am learning scala. I have one basic question.

My question is not about class. It is about objects.

I would like to understand how scala's class instance differs from java class instance.

I have the below code in scala

```
class Employee(var id:Int,var name:String)
{

    def show()
    {
      println("Id : " +id)
      println("Name :"+name)
    }

}

 object obj1
 {
     def main(args: Array[String])
     {
         val emp1 = new Employee(100,"Surender")
         emp1.show
     }
 }
```

I want to know what is obj1?  Can we say obj1 is the instance of class Employee or object of class Employee.

Similarly How does Obj1 differ from emp1?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between object and class in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755345/difference-between-object-and-class-in-scala)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`object` is a shorthand for defining a type and instantiating it in a single declaration. The type of `obj1` is `obj1.type` (you can see this by entering `:t obj1` into the REPL).

> Can we say obj1 is the instance of class Employee or object of class Employee.

No, there is no relationship between `Employee` and `obj1`.

> How does Obj1 differ from emp1?

They're totally different things. A more apt question would be "what does `obj1` have in common with `emp1`?", to which the answer is merely that they share the common ancestor `java.lang.Object`, as all references do.

Comment: They can also access each other's private fields, like here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1755942/4496364.

Comment: @insan-e, no, it needs to be a companion object for that. That's not the case in the this question.

Answer (score 0):

Obj1 is not instance of any named class. It is a single instance on an (implicit constructed by scala) anonymous (inaccessible) class. I think you cannot say that obj1 is instance of Employee. So obj1 is an instance of an anonymous class, and emp1 is an instance of Employee class.