# Understanding class and object in scala

Tags: java, scala

I'm very new to scala and now I have to work on a project which is written both in scala and java. I came across with this-like construction:

```
class SomeType{
    //...
}

trait Trait1 extends scala.AnyRef{
}

trait Trait2 extends extends scala.AnyRef{
}

class MyClass(arg : SomeType) extends Trait1{
    //...
}

object MyClass extends Trait2{
    //...
}
```

It's kind of mind-numbing. As far as I got by reading this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1755521/2786156) we can think of `object`s as just classes with abstract methods. I.e. we could (In my opinion) define some mapping with `Class<T>` object in java.

But in this example `class` and `object` extends ***different*** `trait`s. And that's what I was really confused by. I cannot imagine what it means and why it was used.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: we can't think of object's as classes with abstract methods. Objects are just singletons.

Comment: For jvm object is (not exactly) a regular class let's say `SomeObject`. But scala also generates another class with static value that contains `instance = new SomeClass()`, so when you access `SomeObject.someMethod` you're actually calling `instance.someMethod`

Comment: The answer that you quoted says think of object as 'a singleton of a class that is defined implicitly'.  That is, it is an object too.   Perhaps the following link will help you: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/singleton-objects.html. Most notably it says 'there is no static keyword in scala'.  So object gets used where a java programmer would think static.. why the difference?  they come from different schools of thought.  Scala is heavily influenced by Haskell and Java is heavily influenced by C/C++.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'll try to explain what a Scala `object` is from the perspective of someone who knows Java.

In Java, you can define "normal" class members and `static` class members. When something (for example a member variable) is `static` in Java, then there's only one instance of that member variable, which is shared by all instances of the class.

In Scala, there is no `static`. Compared to Java: whatever you would make `static` in Java, you would put in an `object` in Scala.

A Scala `object` is a singleton - there's only a single instance of it, just like `static` members in Java of which there's only a single instance.

I hope that makes it a little bit more clear what a Scala `object` is exactly.

A Scala `object` can extend classes or traits just like any other class or trait, so that it inherits whatever was defined in the class or trait that it extends. There's really no reason why this should not be possible.

Note that if you have a `class` and an `object` with the same name, then those two belong together - they can see each other's private members. The `object` is called the **companion object** of the class.

Note that this does **not** mean that the `object` is an instance of the class. It is not - it is a separate thing that stands beside the class. Maybe your confusion about the class and object extending different traits comes from a misunderstanding about that point.

Answer (score 3):

A class is just like any other class in other languages. You define class just like any other language with some syntax difference. Also, there are [case classes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/case-classes.html) which comes with some handy methods defined and allows for easy initialization of objects.

```
class Person(val name: String)
val me = new Person("My name")
```

However, object is a class with single object only. This makes it interesting as it can be used to create static members of a class using **companion object**. This companion object has access to private members of the class definition and it has the same name as the class you're defining.

```
class Person(var name: String) {

  import Person._

  def hi(): String = sayHello(name)
}

object Person {
  private def sayHello(name: String): String = "Hello " + name
}

val me = new Person("My name")
me.hi()
```

Also, noteworthy point is that object class is lazily created which is another important point. So, these are not instantiated unless they are needed in our code.

If you're defining connection creation for JDBC, you can create them inside object to avoid duplication just like we do in Java with singleton objects.