# Can an object extend abstract class in scala?

Tags: scala, object, abstract-class

I am newbie to scala . I am trying to create an Object that extends abstract class like show below

```
object Conversions extends UnitConversions
{
 override def inchesToCentimeters(inches:Int) = inches * 2.5
 override def gallonsToLiters(gallons:Int) = gallons * 3.78
 override def milesToKilometers(miles:Int) = miles * 1.6
}

abstract class UnitConversions
{
 def inchesToCentimeters(inches:Int)
 def gallonsToLiters(gallons:Int)
 def milesToKilometers(miles:Int)
}
```

While i try to access the object's member functions i get **()** this expression as output .

```
Conversions.milesToKilometers(20) //I get output ()
```

More over is the below statement valid ???

```
var ucv:UnitConversions = new Conversions
println(ucv.milesToKilometers(3)) // I get output () here as well
```

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to provide a return type for the functions, otherwise they return `Unit`:

```
abstract class UnitConversions {
  def inchesToCentimeters(inches:Int): Double
  def gallonsToLiters(gallons:Int): Double
  def milesToKilometers(miles:Int): Double
}
```

Comment: How can I reconcile `You need to provide a return type for the functions` with: `abstract class F { def f = 42 }`
, then: 
`(new F {}).f` returning: `res0: Int = 42`
`

Comment: In that case, the return type is inferred from the implementation. If your abstract class does not provide a default implementation nor a return type, it is assumed to be a ``Unit`` function.

Comment: Thanks - `abstract class G { def g }`. Then, `class GImpl extends G { override def g: Int = 42 }` fails to compile: `error: overriding method g in class G of type => Unit;`. Any compiler flag or, I'm speculating, scala ticket to require a return type on such methods?

Comment: The compiler flags are -Xfuture -deprecation (for warnings) and personally I love -Xfatal-warnings ;-)

Comment: THanks all .It helped

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this question:

> More over is the below statement valid ???
>
> `var ucv:UnitConversions = new Conversions println(ucv.milesToKilometers(3))`

This doesn't compile. `object` basically means singleton and can be used for "static" methods. It doesn't make sense to create more than one instance of a singleton. Take a look at this question: [Difference between object and class in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755345/difference-between-object-and-class-in-scala)

Comment: what? are you sure you are answering the right question?