# Difference between an object in Java versus an object in Scala

Tags: java, scala

I have started learning Scala.Is there any difference between an object in Java versus an object in Scala. As per my understanding the object created in Scala is singleton. Any other pointers please.

Comment: I think you're confusing the object concept with the [`object` keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1755521/1553851).

Answer (score 4):

In Java, `Object` (upper case) is the top class. All classes extend `Object`. Primitive types (`int`, `long`, etc) don't extend `Object` because they are not a class

In Scala, there's a a different hierarchy. Everything extends class `Any`: reference types extend `AnyRef`, and value types extend `AnyVal`, unlike Java, there are no primitives. (check docs: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/unified-types)

But the `object` you are referring in Scala is a singleton yes. It's very common to have a class that you want to be a singleton. In java there's a pattern to achieve that (for instance http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html), in scala they created the `object` keyword as a shorthand.

there is also a special case: when there's a `class` and an `object` with the same name defined in the same compilation unit, the object is called a companion object, and basically you can think of it as holding the static methods you would have in Java

More on the subject at http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/singleton-objects.html

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are creating an object in Scala. It's not like all object creation is Singleton.

For example:

```
object Shiva { /*some code*/}
```

Will create a singleton object. But if you define a class like you do in Java, you can create multiple instances.

Comment: the `object` keyword must be lowercase in your example