# Why are classes created inside Objects in Scala

Tags: scala

I don't understand why sometimes class are created inside an object in Scala, just like the following code shows.

```
object polynomials { 
  class Poly(terms0: Map[Int, Double]) {
    val terms = terms0 withDefaultValue 0.0

    def +(other: Poly) = new Poly(terms ++ (other.terms map adjust))

    def adjust(term: (Int, Double)): (Int, Double) = {
        val (exp, coeff) = term
        exp -> (coeff + terms(exp))
    }
    override def toString = 
     (for ((exp, coeff) <- terms.tolist.sorted.reverse) yield coeff 
     + ”x^” + exp) mkString “+” 
  }

  val p1 = new Poly(Map(1 -> 2.0, 3 -> 4.0, 5 -> 6,2))
  val p2 = new Poly(Map(0 -> 3.0, 3 -> 7.0)

  p1 + p2
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of reasons for doing this that relate to naming and data hiding.

1. The nested `class` is inside the scope of the `object` rather than in the wider  `package` scope, so it can have a simpler name without clashing with other package classes. It makes an explicit link between the `class` and the `object`.
2. The `class` can be `private` to the `object` so it is not visible outside the scope of the `object`. This is often used for a `class` that implements an abstract interface where only the interface is visible outside the `object`
3. The nested `class` can access members of the `object` directly, including `private` members that are not externally visible.

Answer (score -1):

Defining an object in Scala is like defining a class in Java that has only static methods. However, in Scala an object can extend another superclass, implement interfaces, and be passed around as though it were an instance of a class. (So it's like the static methods on a class but better).

An object has exactly one instance (you can not call new MyObject). You can have multiple instances of a class.

Object serves the same (and some additional) purposes as the static methods and fields in Java.

- Answered taken from this older SO question - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755345/difference-between-object-and-class-in-scala#:~:text=Defining%20an%20object%20in%20Scala,on%20a%20class%20but%20better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755345/difference-between-object-and-class-in-scala#:%7E:text=Defining%20an%20object%20in%20Scala,on%20a%20class%20but%20better)).

So if you have for example a Circle object and a Circle class then
Circle object would have generic properties like PI and methods like CalculateArea() whereas Circle class would have instance specific properties like Colour, Radius etc.

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question